# Tcl: Test whether path is relative or absolute

Tags: tcl

Is there a nice way in Tcl, to test, whether a given path is relative or absolute? Of course I can do it explicitly:

- If it starts with a /, it's absolute.
- If I am on Windows and it starts with \ or X:\ (for some letter X), it's absolte.
- If I am on a Mac and ....
  etc.

This looks to me like re-inventing the wheel, though. This problem seems to be so common (for example, "file normalize" as to do it), that I suspect that there must be something in the Tcl library which is already doing the trick...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a one way. Please note that this solution does not work with symbolic links:

```
# Returns 1 (true) if path is absolute, 0 otherwise. Does not work
# with symbolic links
proc isAbsolute {path} {
    set absolutePath [file normalize $path]
    return [expr {$path eq $absolutePath}]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `file pathtype $path`. It returns `absolute`, `relative`, or `volumerelative`.

Comment: Good idea, but pathtype seems to have a problem (tested on Tcl 8.4 and 8.5 under Cygwin Tcl): For example, both pathes, F:X and /X, are classified as volumerelative (the first means: directory X relative to current directory on drive F:, and the second means directory X directo under the cygwin root), and I can't distinguish them. Onl F:/X would be classified as abolute. I think this is in some way a feature, not a bug, but for me it means I can't use it for my purpose.  :-(

Comment: F:X is relative to your current working directory on volume F: and /X is absolute but dependent on your current volume. So they are both volume relative but for different reasons. It is probably more useful to force the paths to be absolute by using `file normalize` on the path to ensure consistent behaviour.